# What technique is best for dimensionality reduction OR clustering of mixed data?

Tags: python, clustering, dimensionality-reduction, hierarchical-clustering

All,

I have data with mixed types: categorical e.g. colour and numerical. I am trying to reduce the number of dimensions. I thought about using FACTOR ANALYSIS of mixed data, however the python package (prince) seems to not work. Is it possible to use UMAP on mixed data types ?

- **can anybody suggest what dimensionality reduction algo is suitable for mixed data**

For hierarchal clustering, these are the steps i would take so please let me know if i should add anything:

1. create gower matrix
2. pass distance matrix through hierarchal clustering algo
3. Find cut off point for number of clusters and then use these labels
4. Once labels are assigned for each cluster calculate summary stats e.g. mean, mode for each cluster to see what characteristics are.

Does the above seem fair? Is there anything i am missing. I could also use KPROTOTYPES but i want to ensure i have covered other grounds.